# NavigationDrawer update items

Tags: java, android

I'm using the navigation drawer example in Android.  What's the easiest way to change the string items in the adapter dynamically?  Do I just create a new adapter and set it with my new values?

The problem is I'm altering the string items based on user state logged in and logged out. How do I access it from a non static context and just say update list adapter?  It doesn't seem to be re-drawing itself and running my adapter code which is dynamic based on user state, so I guess it runs/inits once and I have to create and load a new adapter if I want to change it later?

Thanks.

Comment: You can simply change items inside the adapter, and then call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`, and your view will be redrawn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given us much to go on (a little code would be nice), but you can update the data in the `ListView` by calling `notifyDatasetChanged()` on the `Adapter`. If you are not using a custom `Adapter` e.g. an `ArrayAdapter` then you can just create a new `Adapter` instance with different `String` values and set it to the `ListView`.

Comment: Stored a member variable in my main activity, created an update function on the navigationd drawer fragment, and called update to change the values using a new adapter.